# How to connect to a server using an external ip (Java)?

Tags: java, networking, mobile

I'm doing a project, I have a server, a client (C #), a client (Android java). I can connect to the server on the local network and use an external ip from the client C #, but from the Java client I can connect only by Wifi. The server on the router port forwarding, I have a static ip address. Help please what's the problem?

Comment: There's quite literally ten million things that could be wrong. There's no way to effectively answer your question without about a full page more details than that.

Comment: Firewall? Either yours or ISP's? Anyway, insufficient information to do more than guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the info you provided, there is nothing wrong.

For your C# client, you can connect it from local network (i assume 192.168.x.x)

and

For your java client, using wifi means local network (also i assumed 192.168.x.x)

so it means that it works well with local network.

So now the main problem is, is your server really online to internet

Please check the following:

1. Is your server accessible via any api testing tools, such as RESTFUL AND SOAPUI using external ip address.
2. Is you android client really online when not using a local network, or you can access it through external ip address.

Comment: I sent my application (client C #) to my friend who lives in another city and he was able to connect to the server via an external ip (10.197.0.xxx). On the client mobile internet is, checked